# Firebase - how to watch for push notifications

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api

I have made a post to the google calendar api to creat a notification channel and 
 watch for event changes:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications

I am using `firebase` how can I deploy a site that watches for posts to the notification channel, `https://example.firebaseapp.com/notifications`?

I have a simple function which posts to the google api to setup the notification channel:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

let { google } = require("googleapis");

let privatekey = require("../config.json");
let axios = require("axios");

let jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_id,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
);

let ids = [];
let promises = [];

function revisedRandId() {
     return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(2, 10);
}

async function main() {
    const token = await jwt.authorize();
    console.log("token" + token.access_token);
    let headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        Authorization: token.token_type + " " + token.access_token
    };
    let data = {
        id: revisedRandId(),
        type: "web_hook",
        address: "https://rguc-calendars.firebaseapp.com/notifications",
        params: {
            ttl: 3600
        }
    };

    axios
        .post(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/thirdyear@rguc.co.uk/events/watch",
            data,
            { headers }
        )
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
}
```

How can I use `firebase` to run this function, and watch for notifications?

Comment: There is no way to trigger Google Cloud Functions through a push notification, such as those sent by Firebase Cloud Messaging. I am a bit lost on what you're trying to accomplish here, as it reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe the purpose of this code?

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry for the confusion, how can I use firebase to listen for  posts to my channel, `https://rguc-calendars.firebaseapp.com/notifications`? After which I intend (somehow) to send a push notification to android and ios apps displaying a notification.

Comment: Cloud Functions can only respond to a URLs it controls, which doesn't seem to be the case for `https://rguc-calendars.firebaseapp.com/notifications`. How are those notifications delivered to `https://rguc-calendars.firebaseapp.com/notifications`?

Comment: It's a http post to the url which you specify in the payload.

Comment: Can you specify your own URL? In that case you could point it to Cloud Functions.

Comment: Yes I will try that